# how can I manipulate my HTML after reading my JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.alert = function(){};
    var defaultCSS = document.getElementById('bootstrap-css');
    function changeCSS(css){
        if(css) $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+ css +'" type="text/css" />'); 
        else $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith(defaultCSS); 
    }
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON("./data/data.json", function(json) {
        console.log(json.length); // this will show the info it in firebug console
      });
    });
</script>
```

I know that json is my JSON object. I want to use that to manipulate my html

if it's the 1st item in my JSON object then

```
      <div class="item active"> <!-- active only appears if it's the first item -->
        <blockquote>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
              <img class="img-circle" src="json[0].image" style="width: 100px;height:100px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <p>json[0].quote</p>
              <small>json[0].person</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </blockquote>
      </div>
```

and I want to repeat the above code n times

Comment: Have you considered a javascript templating library such as [doT.js](http://olado.github.io/doT/index.html) or [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) ?

Comment: Use a loop like `$.each(json, function() ...)` to process the JSON and add it to the DOM.

Comment: JavaScript isn't my strong suite. Can you please show an example. The example doesn't even have to solve the problem for me. Just want to get an idea

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but probably the easiest way would be to build a string and append it to whatever container you want it to live in.

```
$.getJSON("./data/data.json", function(json) {
  $.each(json, function(data) {
    var html = '<p>' + data.quote + '</p>' +
               '<small>' + data.person + '</small>';

    $('#MySuperSpecialDiv').append(html);
  });
});
```

Please note that this won't scale well. If you are going to add much more markup than you already have, you should really consider some sort of templating alternative.

Also, if some one comes in behind you to maintain this project, you probably won't be their favorite person.

Comment: Jusr 1 more question. WHere would this code actually reside? (script tags near the <head tag?

Comment: best practice is to write this in a external js file that is requested right before closing the body tag.

Comment: Thank you but if I do that, how will I insert my HTML in the middle of the page. My div tags need to be between <div class="carousel-inner"> and it's closing tag. If I append it to the end of the file then it would mess up my html layout

Comment: my use of `$('body').append(html);` was just for example. Place a div with a unique id where ever you want your new html to be added and replace `'body'` the the id of the div. `$('#MySuperSpecialDiv').append(html);`